# Wrong overload constructor

Tags: c#, azure

I am using a class call `CloudQueueMessage` from the Azure Storage SDK which has the following two constructors:

```
public CloudQueueMessage(byte[] content);
public CloudQueueMessage(string content);
```

I have some binary data to pass to this class therefore I want to use the constructor that accepts `byte[]`. Here's a contrived example of what I'm trying to do:

```
byte[] data = ... binary data goes here ...;
var cloudMessage = new CloudQueueMessage(data);
```

Surprisingly, I am getting the following compiler error in Visual Studio:

> CS1503    Argument 1: cannot convert from 'byte[]' to 'string'

It's as if the compiler is trying to use the overload that accepts a string and, of course, is unable to convert my byte array into a string.

Please note that I don't want to convert my byte array into a string, I simply need help figuring out why the compiler is not using the appropriate constructor.

In case it's important: I am using version 8.1.1 of the Azure storage nuget package.

**UPDATE:**
 Here's what I see when I press F12 in Visual Studio (notice the `byte[]` constructor is highlighted):
[image: f12 from Visual Studio]

Comment: Shouldn't be doing that. What happens if you explicitly cast `data` as a byte array (...`new CloudQueueMessage((byte[])data)`)?

Comment: I get the exact same error, believe it or not!

Comment: I even tried `var cloudMessage = new CloudQueueMessage((byte[])null);` but I get the same compile error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the `public CloudQueueMessage(byte[] content)` is only available in .NET 4.x and it's not available in .NET Core (I wonder why this overloaded constructor was removed in .NET core).

Therefore, I am using the following workaround in .NET Core:

`var cloudMessage = new CloudQueueMessage(string.Empty);
cloudMessage.SetMessageContent(data);`

Answer (score 1):

Can you drill down into the definition of the constructor and see where it's referenced from? It sounds to me like there is a version conflict somewhere.

Use ILDASM on the `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll` in your root app's bin folder and navigate to the `CloudQueueMessage` class and see if you can find the same constructor. Your app seems to be using an earlier version at runtime somehow.

Did you clear out all obj and bin folders and packages folder too?

Comment: When you say "drill down", do you mean by looking at the source? Their source is on Github so I'll be happy to look but I'm not sure what wee looking for.

Comment: The compiled source, F12, Go to Definition. And then see if the referenced assembly contains the correct constructor overload.

Comment: I updated my original question with a screenshot demonstrating what I see when I press F12